# is it possible to change the pitch of the voice in AVSpeechSynthesizer's voice?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, avspeechsynthesizer

Can I change the pitch of the voice in AVSpeechSynthesizer or putting any effects on the output voice from it so it could sound differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the **pitch** and the **rate** of the spoken sentence.

The `AVSpeechUtterance` class has two relevant properties:

- `pitchMultiplier: Float` (value between **0.5** (lowest pitch) to **2.0** (highest pitch)). The default pitch is **1.0**.
- `rate: Float` (value between two constants: `AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate` (the slowest rate of speech) and `AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate` (the highest rate of speech).

When you create your `AVSpeechUtterance`, simply set these properties appropriately before getting your `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to speak the utterance.

Note: You can also change the **voice** (accent) of `AVSpeechUtterance`.

I hope this helps. Let me know if anything I said was unclear.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any way that I can record/Keep the output voice file from AVSpeechSynthesizer without it being played and the applying any changes to it(such as pitch changes and etc)? Lets assume that Its an app that reads what you type in an exported video to the user in which the voice has been changed... And if such thing isn't possible, Do you know any free Open source alternative to AvSpeechSynthesizer?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do this, and I'm afraid I'm also unaware of any such open source alternatives. You could of course record something yourself (if you know the sentence that will be spoken) and then play that back?

Comment: True i can easily record the voice from user in my app but for some reasons i need to find a way to record it or do something similar with a open source API that works like AvSpeechSynthesizer

Comment: Maybe take a look at the AVFoundation Framework? Here's a link to a nice tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/ And here's a link to some of Apple's resources on it https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/

Comment: I finally got to solve the problem of saving the voice by using an open source TTS API called open ears for iOS. It has a payable option for saving the output TTS voice.

Comment: @ConnorT Is this still the case? I can't see how to do it with open ears

Answer (score 0):

The default pitch is 0.5.

AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate is 0.0

AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate is 1.0 (the highest rate of speech).

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer= [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
synthesizer.delegate=self; 
AVSpeechUtterance *utterances =
[AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:text];utterances.voice
= [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"de-DE"];//change voice utterances.rate=0.5;//default rate
[synthesizer
speakUtterance:utterances];
```